# I am getting operation error no such table in django after renaming the user model

Tags: python, django, exception, model

I created a custom user model and then I added some users in it. After that I tried to change the user model's name and then after changing the name and running the migrations When I tried to open the admin panel I am getting No Such Table operational Error saying no such table (previous name of user model)

For the solution I deleted the complete register app and tried to create model's in another apps. The models got created an they are in admin panel and when I am trying to add some thing in these models I am getting that same error.
OperationalError at /admin/home/test/add/

```
OperationalError at /admin/home/test/add/
no such table: main.reg_boouser
 Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/home/test/add/
Django Version: 2.0.6
 Exception Type:    OperationalError
  Exception Value:  
  no such table: main.reg_boouser
```

Comment: Are you sure that the models got created?

Comment: Did `manage.py makemigrations` pick up the change? Did `manage.py migrate` return any errors? And does `manage.py showmigrations` indicate that your new migrations applied correctly?

Comment: Also try running `manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`. If that doesn't work you should delete your database and start over with the migrations. good luck.

Comment: @Aviral Verma Yes The models got created. Model name is test and I can see the table in admin panel but when i try to add some data in it. It gives me that operational error saying no such table main.reg_boouser. As this boouser table app I have already deleted but I am still getting the error.

Comment: The migrations has been successfully applied to the database as I can see the tables there. But when i try to add anything in any of these table it gives me that operational error.

Comment: Even though I have deleted the app that has that error causing table. I am sure why this table causing the error. Is there any other thing that we could do get completely out of the project. Like something to clean the database.